# Basic charting from a windows service

Tags: .net, windows-services, charts

In order to perform basic charting from a windows service (win32 API) including the generation of bar charts from text file data (saved as .jpeg for instance), I'm stuck about whether .NET 3.5 has this ability built in.

For charting, which references should be added and/or which using statements included?

Even a nudge in the right direction would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [MS Chart Controls](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart). They can be downloaded [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=130f7986-bf49-4fe5-9ca8-910ae6ea442c&DisplayLang=en).

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [ZedGraph](http://zedgraph.org/)?